# Need help in transitioning to vegetarianism/veganism due to allergies. What choices do I have?

Tags: veganism, lacto-ovo-vegetarianism, transitioning-diets, soy, nutritional-deficiency

**Preface**

I've spent a year as a vegetarian and I tried to go vegan (for the ethical argument), but I could only last about a month (28 days, to be precise). As the new year is coming, I'm wondering if I have any tools to help me stop consuming animal products.

After my experiment with veganism (where I nearly died), I learned that I'm genetically anemic, and my doctor recommended I eat fortified foods with iron and I take a B-12 and B-complex every day. Unfortunately, I also learned after an allergy screening due to my weakened position after the vegan/vegetarian diet that I am allergic to soy bean, soy lecithin, most beans, and walnuts (I had to change the brand of b-complex I use as a result that doesn't contain soy). Due to cross contamination, I've pretty much had to eliminate all nuts in my diet.

As a result of all of this, I mostly eat free range chicken, eggs (actually, my sister has chickens and I get them from her), and fish (not free range) as sources of protein. However, I also occasionally eat beef now.

My wife is also severely anemic (we found out during her pregnancy) and just gave birth to our little baby boy five weeks early. Now as we're waiting in the NICU, I'm wondering if my diet may be unsustainable in the future as this little guy (our first child) will need a heavy dairy and meat diet. I'm also afraid that he may have inherited my many allergies as he's especially having a hard time feeding right now.

**TL;DR**

I have allergies to soy, beans, and nuts.

Are there sources of protein/iron/vitamin B that are not soy/bean/nut based that I can use to continue pursuing ethical vegetarianism or (hopefully) veganism, or am I stuck to limiting my diet as best I can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to hear that you are suffering from such allergies and at the same time you're taking steps towards more ethical diet.

I made a list that seem to suit your needs below, but please be aware that I am not a doctor. Always double check with a professional if you are not sure or you are suspicious on some of these foods. They are ideas only :)

Not sure if you're allergic to all legumes, so please ignore these if you are.

- **Quinoa**: This grain is a complete protein, containing all essential amino acids. It is also high in iron and vitamin B.
- **Chia seeds**: These seeds are high in protein, fiber, and omega-3 fatty acids. They are also high in iron and calcium.
- **Hemp seeds**: Hemp seeds are a good source of protein and contain all essential amino acids. They are also high in iron, zinc, and magnesium.
- **Spirulina**: This type of blue-green algae is high in protein, iron, and vitamin B.
- **Green leafy vegetables**: Spinach, kale, and collard greens are all high in iron and vitamin B.
- **Seitan**: This is made from wheat gluten and is high in protein, iron, and calcium.
- ***Tofu**: This is made from soybeans but processed to remove allergens. It is high in protein, iron, and calcium.
- ***Tempeh**: This is made from fermented soybeans and is high in protein, fiber, and vitamins. It is also high in iron and calcium.
- **Lentils**: These legumes are high in protein, fiber, and iron. They are also a good source of vitamin B and calcium.
- **Oats**: These whole grains are high in protein, fiber, and iron. They are also a good source of vitamin B and calcium.
- **Chickpeas**: These legumes are high in protein, fiber, and iron. They are also a good source of vitamin B and calcium.
- **(Sweet) Potatoes**: These starchy vegetables are high in protein, fiber, and iron. They are also a good source of vitamin B and potassium.
- **Swiss chard**: This leafy green vegetable is high in protein, fiber, and iron. It is also a good source of vitamin B and calcium.
- **Black-eyed peas**: These legumes are high in protein, fiber, and iron. They are also a good source of vitamin B and calcium.
- **Brussels sprouts**: These cruciferous vegetables are high in protein, fiber, and iron. They are also a good source of vitamin B and calcium.
- **Brown rice**: This whole grain is high in protein, fiber, and iron. It is also a good source of vitamin B and magnesium.
- **Amaranth**: This grain is high in protein, fiber, and iron. It is also a good source of vitamin B and calcium.
- **Broccoli**: This cruciferous vegetable is high in protein, fiber, and iron. It is also a good source of vitamin B and calcium.
- **Artichokes**: These vegetables are high in protein, fiber, and iron. They are also a good source of vitamin B and magnesium.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you so much for this! I love most of these and am excited to try this out. Thank you so much!